Polarion: To insert in a Polarion document an "EA shortcut" to a particular EA diagram
In Polarion, is there a way to insert/embed in a Polarion doc an "EA shortcut" (*1) to a particular EA diagram? This is so I can click on the shortcut and EA will run and open at the particular diagram specified by the shortcut.
Note
(1) EA = Sparx Enterprise Architect
Thanks
